# Помогите заменить изображение

Tags: javascript, css3

Имеется галерея http://prorab-service.ru/1/index.html помогите найти код где можно заменеть на свои изображения(javascript не знаю поэтому не смог найти)спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Картинки у Вас задаются с помощью `js` в файле `demo.js`

Получают картинки так

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/',
    data: {
      format: 'json',
      method: 'flickr.interestingness.getList',
      api_key: '7617adae70159d09ba78cfec73c13be3' // jshint ignore:line
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback'
    ...
```

Информацию о библиотеке можно прочитать [тут](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery#initialization)

Чтобы добавить изображение

```
var gallery = blueimp.Gallery([
    'https://example.org/images/banana.jpg',
    'https://example.org/images/apple.jpg',
    'https://example.org/images/orange.jpg'
]);
```

или

```
var gallery = blueimp.Gallery([
    {
        title: 'Banana',
        href: 'https://example.org/images/banana.jpg',
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        thumbnail: 'https://example.org/thumbnails/banana.jpg'
    },
    {
        title: 'Apple',
        href: 'https://example.org/images/apple.jpg',
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        thumbnail: 'https://example.org/thumbnails/apple.jpg'
    }
]);
```

Comment: Заменил на свою ссылку и никакого эффекта

Comment: @Ruslan `demo.js` файл вообще удалить

Comment: Извеняюсь а как теперь вставить мои картинки в каком коде?

Comment: @Ruslan добавил в ответ

Comment: Большое спасибо. Как проголосовать за вас?

Comment: Ни как не срабатывает миниатюра изображения использую второй код в ответе